# PHP logging script error

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'BinKill', 'password removed', 'tk_development');
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $date = Date("d/mY, g:i:s");
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    } else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO `logs` (ip,date) VALUES (`$ip`, `$date`)";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        if(!$result){
            die("Could not Execute Query: " . mysqli_error());
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }

?>
```

Above is the code I'm using to try and log the IP of the user accessing the page and the date of which they accessed it. However when this is ran, all that is returned is: Could not Execute Query:

No error. Not sure what's going on exactly.

Comment: Try adding `ini_set('display_errors',1);  error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the start of your PHP code and try, report back to me what you get.

Comment: Thanks for that little bit of code.

Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /home/binkill/public_html/portfolio/index.php on line 13
Could not Execute Query:

Comment: Should be `mysqli_error($conn)`

Comment: Try this [$query](http://pastebin.com/7xB4Tbsf). I apologise for not using code formatting here, but it's not possible with that.

Comment: Ended up fixing the mysqli_error and it returned Could not Execute Query: Unknown column '66.97.29.2' in 'field list' I think I can figure it out from here. Will report back when done

Comment: Try what I suggested, it might work.

Comment: You used backticks rather than single quote around your strings. That's the whole issue.

Comment: Thanks developerwjk, figured that out just before you posted that. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is the use of backticks(`) on the values. Only use backticks on the 
table and column names (only necessary for reserved keywords)

Change

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `logs` (ip,date) VALUES (`$ip`, `$date`)";
```

To

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `logs` (ip,date) VALUES ('$ip', '$date')";
```

Comment: **Moderator Note:** I've removed the comments here. Comments should be used to discuss the topic of this answer, anything else should be taken to chat.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of a syntax error, but however your `mysqli_*` error code is incorrect as you never specified which connection to give an error for, it *should* be:

```
mysqli_error($conn)
```

instead of

```
mysqli_error()
```

You are also using backticks incorrectly, your correct code should be:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `logs` (ip,date) VALUES ('$ip', '$date')";
```

which is why you were getting the error:

> Could not Execute Query: Unknown column '66.97.29.2' in 'field list'